# Opening a url on browser from an activity on KeyGuard

Tags: android, lockscreen, keyguard

I have an activity that runs on the top of my secured lockscreen/ keyguard (The pattern key guard). The top view of the activity has the following flags:

```
getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Then there is a button on the activity that should open google.com on the browser when the button is clicked and put in the right pattern on my key guard. However, when I click the button and put in the right pattern, google.com is not opened. The browser is opened, but it does not open google.com. What is interesting if change my keyguard to non-secure(swipe key guard instead of pattern), the browser opens to google.com. Anyone knows why? Here is the listener code when the button is clicked:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: on which version of android you are testing, I tried on my development environment on Android 2.3.6 and it is working fine.

Comment: I am testing it on 4.4.2. Are u using secure keyguard (pattern or password? Does your browser open google.com?

Comment: I have tried with all possible options pattern,password and PIN. Working fine with all. Let me give a try with 4.4.2 as well.

Comment: I'm facing same issue? Did you solved the issue? I have also tried all the things like setting flags on Intent and all. `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`.

Comment: @pyus13 Did you tried it on 4.4.2? I have tested this on Nexus 4 and Nexus 5, not working? Any idea why?

Comment: ya i have tried it on Nexus 4 same here. Its not working. It might be some security improvement in passing data to any third party application from lock screen.